# Find the general solution to differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could someone please help me with this

if  $\frac{dx}{dt} = 2x$ and $x(1)=x(0)+1$ find $x(t)$.

I started off with:

$$\frac12 \int \frac1x \,  dx = \int 1\, dt$$

$$\frac12 \ln(x) = t+c$$

$$x=e^{2(t+c)}$$

where should I go from here?

Comment: Where did that 5 come from? Shouldn't it be a $2$?

Comment: Sorry, yes your right

Comment: do you solve for c to get c=-1/2 ln (exp(2) -1)

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- Since your equation is linear and the coefficients are constants, you can seek for solutions of the form $x(t) = e^{r t}$, which after substitution leads you to $r = 2$ and hence the general solution is given by $$x(t) = C e^{2 t}.$$
- Note that the solution above is equivalent to yours, identifying $C = e^{2c}$ (use the properties of the exponential, namely, $e^{a+b} = e^a e^b$).
- Now is time to find $C$, given that $x(1) = x(0) + 1$. Substitute this data to have: $$ C e^{2} = C + 1. $$ Can you solve for $C$?

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I believe C would rearrange to C= (1)/(e^2-1). So x(t)= (e^(2t))/(e^2-1) ??

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You can also work with $c$ instead of working with $C$, if you wish so.

Comment: A lot cleaner than with the $c$. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have $x(t)=e^{2t+2c}$. Thus, you can plug in for $x(t=1)=x(t=0)+1$ and solve for $c$.
$$x(t=1)=e^{2*1+2*c}=x(t=0)+1=e^{2*0+2*c}+1$$
$$e^{2+2*c}=e^{2*c}+1$$
$$e^2*e^{2c}=e^{2c}+1$$
As mentioned in the previous answer, solve for $e^{2c}$.
$$e^{2c}*(e^2-1)=1$$
$$e^{2c}=\frac{1}{e^2-1}$$
Therefore, solve for $c$.
$$c=\frac{1}{2} \ln(\frac{1}{e^{2c}-1})$$